# Is it necessary to use "will" twice on the text below

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, orthography

> Thanks for your feedback. We will make the changes and be ready for tomorrow’s call

Answer (score 3):

> We will make the changes and be ready for tomorrow's call.
>
> We will make the changes and will be ready for tomorrow's call.
>
> We will make the changes and we will be ready for tomorrow's call.

All three versions are grammatical and mean the same thing. We usually write the first for brevity.